# Auto post picture to instagram as story

Tags: instagram, publish, instagram-api

I want to know, if there is an api that supports to post/publish automatically a picture as a instagram story.

Currently I am using the instagram4j api that works perfectly to publish pictures in the regular feed, but I want to be able to plan that every day a picture is published as a story.

Is there such an api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is something other developers have requested on the GitHub repo issues section for the Instagram4j API.

https://github.com/brunocvcunha/instagram4j/issues/42

Might be worth following this and +1 ing the issue.

As off now, Instagram's official API doesn't allow this unfortunately.

An alternative might be to check this repo on GitHub. 
https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Request/Story.php

I haven't tested it myself but that might be something worth considering.